# Does Kripke hold a view of free logic?

Tags: logic, modal-logic, kripke

if Kripke doesn't want to accept Barcan's formula（the changed form in free logic） - given his essentialism - one solution is free logic. 
So does Kripke say that he accepts free logic or?

Comment: Yes and no. "*Kripke asserts... that the unrestricted rule of necessitation is a derived rule in his system... On the other hand Kripke’s system quite plausibly deserves
the name ‘free logic’, since it does not contain universal instantiation*", Bacon, [Quantificational Logic and Empty Names](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/p/pod/dod-idx/quantificational-logic-and-empty-names.pdf?c=phimp).